# Need explanation on declaring a property lazy on a custom type

Tags: swift

Hello so I have a `UIButton` and I subclassed it to a `CustomButton`

Now in another file I tried 
`private lazy var button = CustomButton()` 
and I got an error saying *Cannot convert value of type UIButton to specified type RoundedButton*

But if I do this `private lazy var button: CustomButton = CustomButton()`
it works. I just need an understanding why the one above doesn't work, but the one on the bottom works?

I've read that for lazy propers you can't infer types, but `private lazy var button = UIButton()` works.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is not with the "private lazy". 
You have to use "**button:CustomButton**" because "Swift is statically typed on the other hand. Meaning variables have type. You can't place any object you want into a variable. The compiler will make sure you only place compatible objects into variables."